# sorting 100000 elements does not complete

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

my bubblesort program sorts 10000 elements in 4 seconds and lists every one of them. If I change the size of the array to sort to 100000, it stops part way through...

Can anyone please let me know how I can resolve this issue? The code works fine for 10000 elements btw. Do I need to allocate memory using malloc? if so, could you advise me how to implement this as I am fairly new to c

```
#define SIZE 100000

for(i = 6; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    values[i] = (rand()%20000*3.237);
    printf("%f\t", values[i]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stops part way through"? Do the program just hang? Does it crash? Is there any errors or other messages?

Comment: it just stops displaying any more numbers. Doesn't crash, doesn't say press any key to continue... it just stays still and nothing happens

Comment: int, should I chane it to long then?

Comment: Is that program running in a 32/64 bit system?

Comment: Actually, changing the value of i to long makes no difference...

Comment: You should try to print out "i" too in the printf to see where it stops. In what environment you run that code? Console output under windows?

Comment: its running on a 64 bit system

Comment: yeah a console output (cmd) in windows. Just pressed ctrl + f5 to run the program from VS

Comment: What's the declaration of `values`?

Comment: Could you please show us the declaration of 'i' and the allocation of the values array?

Comment: Oh and what has this loop to do with sorting at all??

Comment: what is : "stops part way through...", where is sorting here ""

Comment: the sorting is elsewhere, sorry for the confusion! I'm creating random numbers and allocating them to the array. The program does actually complete, it took 106 seconds to sort 100,000 elements. What I can't understand though, is why can't I scroll up in command prompt to view the whole output? It just shows about 20,000 elements and the preceding output is cut off..

Comment: Thats the console buffer. So the loop reached the end you say? You just don't see the first output?

Comment: Yeah, eventually, it completed the sort! How can I stop the console buffer and have it display everything? Do you think my compluter would crash if I tried to display that many values? Thanks for your response by the way!

Comment: Why does `i` start at `6`? It probably should start at `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Remind the range of your counter-variable;
16bit int works until 65535 ;-)

Comment: ahhhh, how can I make the numbers larger? use double?

Comment: @John ***usually*** `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, but if you want big numbers and cross-platform code, use `int64_t` or `int32_t`.

Comment: Shouldn't matter for 100000 elements.

Comment: Outside some small embedded devices with not enough RAM to sort 100000 numbers, when did you last see a 16-bit `int`?

Answer (score 0):

How much time did you wait??

Let me remind you that bubble sort is `O(n^2)`.

So if `10^4` inputs lead to  `4s`, then `10^5` inputs lead to an estimate of `4 * (10^5)^2 / (10^4)^2 = 400 s = 6 mins and 40 s`.

Comment: He said dumping the contents of values array stopped. Seems like bubble sort was already done.

Comment: I reread and no mention of that. We have no idea what he is doing.

Comment: so sorry guys! This is the answer that solves it all. I'm impatient and didn't wait. the program took ages to complete and it looked like it had stopped. If you're still bothering with stupid me, please could you explain why the cmd prompt doesn't show all the values I requested it to output ie. all 100000 elements?

Comment: I told you. Its the console buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the console buffer size as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686044.aspx)

```
COORD size;
size.X = 200;
size.Y = 30000;
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetConsoleWindow(), size);
```

experiment with it

Comment: You can thank with upvote and accept. I would recommend you to do the output into a file instead of the console though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write into a file; try to use fprintf; so you can switch between console or file stream. And try to use gimmics like "**FUNCTION**" (GNU) to use log-messages that are transparent and unique.
You're welcome :)